# Remove certain words and set word at end of string in files

Tags: command-line, scripting, regular-expression, string, pattern-matching

I have a bunch of files that contain strings similar to:

```
Get<1>(abc)
Get<2>(xyz)
```

How can I recursively search for all files with the above pattern and remove everything before the first '(' and place a string afterwards?

Desired output:

```
abc.val()
xyz.val()
```

abc and xyz can change to anything, and the number between '<' and '>' don't matter.

Edit:

The files extensions are .cc and .h.

The string also always starts with Get.

Comment: Welcome, do these files have a specific extension?

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity The file extensions are .cc and .h

Comment: Is `Get` what we're keying on here?

Comment: @glenn jackman Everything before the first character after the parenthesis, so `Get<1>(` can be checked. The number can change to anything.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that the number can change. But will we see `Put<1>(something)`? Is it always **Get**?

Comment: Yes, it will always be `Get`. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GNU `grep` to find files that contain at least one occurrence of the pattern and GNU `sed` to do the substitution in-place:

```
ere='Get<[[:digit:]]+>\(([[:alnum:]_]+)\)'
grep -rlEZe "$ere" . |
  xargs -r0 sed -i -E "s/$ere/\1.val()/g"
```

Here `[[:alnum:]_]+` matches sequences of one or more alphanumeric characters or underscores. Change to `[^()]*` for 0 or more characters other than `(` or `)`.

Comment: This seems close to what I'm looking for. The grep was able to find the files, but seems like there's an issue with `sed`. I'm getting `sed: -e expression #1, char 19: invalid reference \1 on 's' command's RHS` (maybe an issue with the grouping)